# BeautifulSoup: Skip html element

Tags: python, html, dom, beautifulsoup, scrape

I have the following html structure: This is only a section of it but I think this snippet is good enough to explain my problem.

```
<tr>
<td> Color Digest </td>
<td> AgAkAZwCJgMZ </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Color Digest </td>
<td> 2,36,156,38,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, </td>
</tr>
```

I have following code to extract the next sibling of "Color Digest" tag

```
for td in soupPage.html.findAll('td'):
    if td.text == 'Color Digest':
        if td.nextSibling.text != " ":
            a = set()
            a = "[" + td.nextSibling.text.strip(",") + "]"
            print a
```

But I want to skip `<td> AgAkAZwCJgMZ </td>`
and get the value in `<td> 2,36,156,38,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, </td>`

What is the best beautifulsoup mechanism I can follow to obtain this?

Comment: What's the condition to skip AgaAkAZwCJgmZ? Is it because it's exactly that value? Because it's the first one? Because it's one without commas? Because it's 12 characters long? Because the next one is really long? Need more info to answer question, I think.

Comment: I don't have a condition I don't want the first element after color digest because its a base64 value. THe second color digest is actually decoded value.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this this way:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<tr>
<td> Color Digest </td>
<td> AgAkAZwCJgMZ </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Color Digest </td>
<td> 2,36,156,38,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, </td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
output = soup.find_all('td', text = re.compile(" Color Digest "))[1].find_next('td').text


print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

More html (entire table for example) would help to write something more robust.

If you know the string to exclude. With bs4 4.7.1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<tr>
<td> Color Digest </td>
<td> AgAkAZwCJgMZ </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Color Digest </td>
<td> 2,36,156,38,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, </td>
</tr>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
elems = [item.text for item in soup.select('td:contains("Color Digest") + td:not(:contains("AgAkAZwCJgMZ"))')]
print(elems)
```

If you don't then use index on returned list

```
elems = [item.text for item in soup.select('td:contains("Color Digest") + td')][1]
```